# "What in the name of Merlin are you doing?" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

> "**What in the name of Merlin are you doing?**" said Ron, watching her as though fearful for her sanity.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sub>

What does the sentence truly mean? Is "in the name of Merlin" an idiom? I get the meaning of "in the name of": *as someone else’s official representative*, but I am not sure about the meaning of the whole phrase.

Comment: Related question on ELU: [What's the meaning of “in God's name”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25605/whats-the-meaning-of-in-gods-name)

Comment: Note that in the _Harry Potter_ series, _Merlin_ seems to be used a lot by the Wizarding community where Muggle expressions would contain some sort of reference to God or Jesus: “in the name of Merlin”, “Merlin’s beard”, etc.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm wondering why it hasn't put: "in the God's name"?

Comment: @dan: In monotheistic ("there is only one God"; Christiantity, Islam,...) contexts, the standard English reference is just ***God***, with no article. But we do include the article with ***the Lord***.

Comment: @dan It's deliberate. It's to give an everyday phrase a magical equivalent, making you feel like you're part of a different, but related world

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original phrase was "in the name of God". The idea was that the speaker must tell the truth. They must swear an oath.

So:

Judge: *Tell me, did you steal the bread?*

Accused: *In the name of God, I swear that I did not steal the bread.*

or

Lord of the manor: *In the name of God man, What are you doing at my door?*

Interloper: *My lord I am only a poor peasant, trying to beg a crumb. This I swear.*

EDIT

As Sarriesfan points out in a comment. "in the name of Merlin" is an invention of the author, J.K. Rowling. It is not an idiom. She uses the name of a famous wizard from folklore as a euphemism for 'God'.

Comment: it might be worth mentioning to avoid any confusion that  "In the name of Merlin" is not a standard idiom, it's something made up by J.K. Rowling to fit the background of Harry Potter.

Comment: @Sarriesfan - Good point, I'll add that.

Comment: i don't think it's a euphemism. Well, maybe in-univerise it is. But the point is she's taken an everyday phrase and made a magical equivalent. it's more of a reference. As a reader, you're supposed to notice the parallel, it's one of the things that makes Harry Potter so enjoyable and imersive to me